Undefined behavior with unions
While working with 3D points, I came across this approach to type definition :
union point_3d {
    struct {
        GLdouble x, y, z;
    } coord;

    GLdouble tab[ 3 ];
};

Thus, the coordinates can be accessed both by name and by subscript, using for example p.coord.x and p.tab.[0] interchangeably.
This is more useful than just typedef GLdouble point_3d[3]; in that unions support direct assignment (and of course, we can access coordinates by name), but also more useful than struct point_3d { glDouble x, y, z; }; in that the type is directly iterable without using sizeof.
But, the actually important question : Is this safe ? Is this portable ? I haven't been able to find anything to suggest it isn't, but I haven't been able to confirm with that it is guaranteed, so I'm asking here to people hopefully more knowledgeable than I.
(while I am interested to know if this works on Windows, I'm specifically referring to POSIX portability. Windows is only of secondary importance to me )

C allows type-punning through unions.
That means you can write to one member of the union (for example the structure), and read from another member (the array). And the opposite way of course.
The big possible problem is if the structure contain any padding between elements or not. If it does then it does not match up with the array. It's unlikely in this case though.

I guess an assert could be used to make sure that no padding has snuck in. In C23 static_assert(sizeof(union point_3d) == sizeof(GLdouble[3])); should suffice.

@TedLyngmo That is an overly stringent test as padding after the coord and tab members is not important if it snuck in.  Something like static_assert(sizeof(point_3d.coord) == sizeof(point_3d.tab),""); is a better test.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Is it really allowed to add padding around an array? I thought the size of union foo { type x[X]; } had to be the same as sizeof(type[X]).

@TedLyngmo,  Consider union foo { char bar[3]; struct baz { char a,b,c; }; short whiz;}; with potential size 4 (1 pad bayte after .bar/.baz.  Size of .bar and .baz are both 3.

@chux-ReinstateMonica True, that would ruin the day :) I was thinking of the cases where the members are overlap 1:1 and have the same alignment, but sure, if there are other members messing with that, it wouldn't work.

@TedLyngmo The point being a 3rd member may be the catalyst for padding and thus demos that padding is possible in a union.  Yet even with 2: char [3] and char a,b,c there is no specification that requires no padding and so padding is possible even if unlikely.  unions could live in even byte address land for example.

The C Standard, as interpreted by clang and gcc, only defines the behavior when the lvalue is of the form unionLvalue.member.  Even lvalues of the form *(unionLvalue.arrayMember+index) will not be consistently recognized as capable of identifying the same storage as other union members.  I would not trust clang or gcc to reliably process such code without using -fno-strict-aliasing.
